# Extracting specific data from text file - bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

i have a huge text file (~4.5GB in size) that holds ~48 million lines.
all line are in the following syntax:

```
    country01/city01/street01/building01
    country01/city01/street01/building02
    country01/city01/street02/building01
    country01/city01/street02/building02
    country01/city02/street01/building01
    .
    .
    etc...
```

i'm trying to find a quick way to cut out the street names and the amount of buildings it holds.
i tried various combinations of `sed` and `awk` with the `wc -l` option but it gets messy and i'm definitely missing something.

will appreciate any help!

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: `cut -d '/' -f3- file.txt` maybe...

Comment: @Paolo a list of all streets with their building quantity like
country01>city01>street02 = 200 etc...

Comment: @GadHayut Show the exact desired output in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to know the amount of buildings in a a street, you can do the following:

```
$ cut -d'/' -f-3 file | sort | uniq -c
```

This will give you a sorted list of streets and a count next to it

```
2 country01/city01/street01
2 country01/city01/street02
1 country01/city02/street01
```

If there might be duplicates in your list you can do this:

```
$ sort -u file | cut -d'/' -f-3 | uniq -c
```

If you really have an enormous file that might not fit into your memory and `sort` takes a bit long, you can do the following:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=SUBSEP="/"}{a[$1,$2,$3]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}' file
```

or if you might have duplicates:

```
$ awk '($0 in a){next}{print; a[$0]}' file | awk 'BEGIN{FS=SUBSEP="/"}{a[$1,$2,$3]++}END{for(i in a) print a[i],i}'
```

Comment: thank you! works great and it's exactly what i needed, cheers

Comment: sorry guys, new here :)

Comment: @GadHayut No worries. It is SO who started with a new feature test which just confuses everybody